# Extracting all 10 digit numbers from a data frame entry (text)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, object

I have a pandas data frame with just one column which contains text (words and numbers).
I want to extract all 10 digit numbers from the text but can't manage to convert the pd.series object in an iterable object like a list.

I tried something like:

```
def find_number(text):
    num = re.findall(r'[0-9]+',text)
    return " ".join(num)
```

and

```
df['List1']=df['Header 1'].apply(lambda x: find_number(x))
```

But this still gives me an non-iterable object.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove the `" ".join()`?

Comment: @Guy why? `findall` returns a list of strings. That is not where the problem lies

Comment: @DeepSpace as far as I understand the OP wants a list, but get a string instead.

Comment: max please provide a [mcve] and see [ask] you need to provide an example that mimics your solution as well as your intended output. This is the bare minimum when asking kind strangers for help on the internet

Comment: Hi, sorry for making it a bit complicated. Its my first time posting here. I hav to re-read the guidelines for posting. Your help is amazing and much appreciated. Exapmle looks like this in each row of the data frame: "apibdnvcponsdvcopn  üiounasdcopnqdc  07082021  owidcnqüwoeic number one 1234567890  number two 0987654321" I Just want to have something iterable with 1234567890 and 0987654321 in it. Thanks a lot guys

Comment: When using "df['B'] = df['Header 1'].str.findall(r'(\d{10})')" it will return all numbers but still in a non-iterable object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the regex from `'[0-9]+'` to `'\d{10}'` to get only results with 10 digits and remove `" ".join()` to leave the results as list

```
def find_number(text):
    return re.findall(r'\d{10}', text)

df['List1'] = df['Header 1'].apply(lambda x: find_number(x))
# or without separate function
df['List1'] = df['Header 1'].apply(lambda x: re.findall(r'\d{10}', x))


print(df['Header 1'])
# 0    apibdnvcponsdvcopn üiounasdcopnqdc 07082021 owidcnqüwoeic number one 1234567890 number two 0987654321
# 0    Name: Header 1, dtype: object

print(df['List1'])
# 0    [1234567890, 0987654321]
#      Name: List1, dtype: object
```